# Practical applications of integration by substitution where integrand is unknown

Tags: integration

What practical applications of integration by substitution are there in which the integrand is unknown?

This application to probability is the only one I could find: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Application_in_probability

Comment: Reposted at https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/16709/77